# Crashing when masking an image

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am trying to mask an image with a "mask image". It worked fine the first time. But when I try one more time within the application with same mask image, the application crashes. When trying with another mask image it works fine. Why does this happen?

Console shows `<Error>: CGImageMaskCreate: invalid mask bits/component: 4294967295.`

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

    CGImageRelease(maskRef);
    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(masked);

    return img2;
}

fun1()
{
view.image=[self maskImage:image1 withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
}

fun2()
{
view.image=[self maskImage:image1 withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]]; view.image=[self maskImage:image1 withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]];
}

fun3()
{
view.image=[self maskImage:image1 withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
view.image=[self maskImage:image1 withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
}
```

When calling `fun1` and `fun2`, apllication works fine. Application is crashing when calling `fun3`.

Comment: It sounds like something is being released from underneath you, but without more detail or sample code I don't know how we'll be able to answer your question.

Comment: Do you have the error from GDB? Run your program in debug mode and I should indicate the error

Answer (score 1):

Why are you releasing maskRef?
You shouldn't because yo didn't retained it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are trying to do, without the memory leaks or crashes:

```
    - (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image
              withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
        CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
        CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;  
        CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                      CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                      CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                      CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                      CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                      CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                      NULL, // decode should be NULL
                                      FALSE // shouldInterpolate
                                      );

        CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageRef, mask);
        CGImageRelease(mask);
        UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
        CGImageRelease(masked);
        return maskedImage;
}
```